# Swift 3.0 stringFromStringNumberOrNil replacement not found. App gives error "Ambiguous reference to member 'value' or Ambiguous use of 'value'"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my previous app , we have used

```
let value = String.stringFromStringNumberOrNil(myProperty?.value)
valueLabel.text = value
```

In above code 'myProperty.value' was kind of 'Any' Class

When i am trying to convert the same code to swift 3.0 app cause error

I have wrote :

```
 var value1 : Int = myProperty.value as Int
```

or

```
 var value1 : String = aylaProperty.value as! String
```

App Gives error :

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'value'
```

What should i do for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `String`s initializer

```
let myPropertyValue:Any = 6
let x = myPropertyValue as! Int
let value = String(x)
let valueLabel = UILabel()
valueLabel.text = value
```